# Code-first Entity Framework : foreign key - invalid object name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, runtime-error, code-first

I'm having trouble with Entity Framework and the code-first approach.

Foreign key will not link properly

Here is the error page: (https://prnt.sc/JUWTdRVCEWq7)

```
public class Organisme
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null! ;
    public string Description { get; set; } = null! ;
    public string Image { get; set; } = null! ;

    public Soort Soort { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class Soort
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public Geslacht Geslacht { get; set; } = null!;

    public ICollection<Organisme> Organismes { get; set; } = null!;
}


modelBuilder.Entity<Soort>().HasMany(a => a.Organismes).WithOne(b => b.Soort);


public async Task<Organisme?> GetByIdAsync(int id)
{
    using OrganismeContext oc = new();
    return await oc.Organismes.AsNoTracking()
                   .Include(x => x.Soort)
                   .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ID == id);
}
```

By removing `.Include(x => x.Soort)`, I no longer get the error, but the value becomes `null` which is not what I want

Adding `.HasForeignKey(c => c.Soort)` gives a whole different error

> InvalidOperationException: 'Soort' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'Organisme' because it is configured as a navigation.

Error pages: https://prnt.sc/1GL3-CgD1ruj and https://prnt.sc/GymTfEIhXy5x

Comment: You have your navigation property (`Soort`) but no foreign key column, so EF doesn't know how to link the two up, hence why you get error when trying to include. Add both a Foreign Key Property and a Navigation Property to your entity model, so for example, `class Organisme { [ForeignKey(nameof(Soort)] public int SoortId {get; set;} public Soort Soort {get; set;} }`

Comment: @nbokmans Thanks for your help. The error has significantly lessend in size
Error: (https://prnt.sc/wPDoNQ2eDzDB)

Comment: That looks like you haven't actually added code-first migration & applied it to database. Did you `dotnet dotnet-ef migrations add NameOfMigration` and `dotnet dotnet-ef database update`?

Comment: @nbokmans First I did `Add-migration Init` then i did `update-database`
I'll look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have your navigation property (`Soort`) but no foreign key column, so EF
> doesn't know how to link the two up, hence why you get error when trying to
> include. Add both a Foreign Key Property and a Navigation Property to your entity model, so for example,
> `class Organisme { [ForeignKey(nameof(Soort)]  public int SoortId {get; set;} public Soort Soort {get; set;} }`

from @nbokmans in comments